# Is $params a reserved word in PHP 7.2?

Tags: php, parameters, reserved

I just made a migration and something got me astonished. I have this function inside a class:

```
function selectEnums($name,$table,$filed, $params = '')
{
    $fieldName = $name. $this->name;
    if(is_array($params) && sizeof($params) > 0)
    {
        foreach($params as $var => $newValue)
        {
            $$var = $newValue;
        }
    }
    $res = $this->getEnums($table,$field, $this->db);
    $this->debug('res after getEnums');
    $this->debug($res);
    $params['options'] = array();
    foreach($res as $v)
    {
        $params['options'][] = $v;
    }
    .....
}
```

Now, I am getting:

> PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use string offset as an array
>   in ....

at this line: `foreach($res as $v)`

Thanks to the previous debug, I am 100% certain that `$res` is an array. Now, here is the tricky thing: If I change the variable from `$params` to `$parames`, it works just fine. What's even worst, this line works fine:  `if(is_array($params) && sizeof($params) > 0)` and the Fatal error is thrown at other line where there is nothing to do with `$params`.

So it's working with that change, buy WHY??? Any ideas? Maybe a php.ini config? A reserved word? I haven't find it on PHP docs.

Thanks

Comment: Not that I know of (which means nothing). Why are you checking for an array in `if(is_array($params)` but assume `$params` is an array in `$params['options']`? If `$params` always is an array, don't default it to a string, but use `$params = []` in your parameters

Comment: Thanks. $params = [] works great, thanks for the tip. Seems to be a glitch on the server because today it wasn't working, so I changed it back to $params and worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all reserved words in `PHP` doesn't start with a `$` sign but rather they are defined without leading sign and should be capitalized as well. e.g

```
const MY_RESERVE_WORD = value;
```

or with

```
define(MY_RESERVE_WORD, value);
```

So there's no such reserved word `params` as you can test the following code at [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org)

```
$params = [1, 2, 2];

foreach($params as $var => $newValue)
{
    $$var = $newValue;
}
```

Possibly `$params` defined as `constant` in any of the `lib/framework` you are using.

Hope this makes it clear the idea of constants in `PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

The error message has nothing to do with $params and everything to do with $res, which you're passing as an array to foreach at that line. Evidently getEnums is returning a string, or at least not an array.

EDIT: Also, if this is meant to import the elements of $params into the symbol table (i.e., with the array keys becoming variable names):

```
foreach($params as $var => $newValue)
        {
            $$var = $newValue;
        }
```

... it can be written more simply as:

```
extract($params);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Didn't know about extract(), works great! Thanks a lot. About the error message, getEnums is returning an array, I am sure because I am debugging $res and it prints as an array, that's the confusing part of this. Now, it seems to be a glitch on the server because today it wasn't working again, so I changed the variable from $parames to $params again and worked fine. I guess the server has some issues

Comment: PHP has a little-known syntax feature that treats strings similarly to a character array. For example: $str = "AEIOU"; echo $str{1}; would print E. I susupected something like that may have been going on in the debug function. Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: Also, be sure to understand the optional flag arguments for extract(). It can behave in different ways if a variable with the same name already exists depending on which flags are passed. Your extracted variable may or may not overwrite the existing variable, may not get set at all, or may have a different (prefixed) name than expected.